# Does this sentence need a question mark

Tags: questions

In trying to stay ahead of the RFP hitting, would you please review and update the attached project descriptions

Comment: Yes, in formal English it would, but commonly native speakers could use a period.

Comment: It depends on whether the intent is to ask a favour or to politely give an instruction.

Answer (score 1):

It is a question. Questions are always followed by a question mark in English.